# Using Spring Reactor to retrieve data from relational database

Tags: java, spring, reactive, reactor

Does it make sense to use reactive programming usind Spring Reactor when we get data from a relational database or when we call an external API endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can make sense in some cases.

For remote API invocation its possible that it will support a “reactive” way of work. In this case you can use WebClient as a reactive alternative to the battle tested RestTemplate.

You can read about the comparison [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webclient-resttemplate)

Now with Relational data access things are more complicated. 
JDBC is not reactive by nature, however there are relational databases that support a reactive way of communication.

There is a reactive alternative of JDBC:  called [r2dbc](https://github.com/r2dbc/) and some databases have indeed reactive drivers.
There is also an integration with Spring Data, see [spring-data-r2dbc project](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-r2dbc)

IMHO this is not ready for production usage though and can be considered as a work in progress that will be done anyway sooner or later.

Comment: So in conclusion for remote API requests it's preferable to use reactive approach but for relational databases it's not fully mature yet

Comment: I agree with rdbms part. As for remote calls it depends. Reactive server can serve more calls simultaneously but its more complicated to implement, debug and is not faster in terms of processing speed...